# Responding to the appearance of the on-screen keyboard in windows store c#/XAML app

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am developing an app which has some text inputs, and I want to show on-screen keyboard such that it does not hide the app and replace the keyboard. MSDN has provided [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Keyboard-Events-Sample-866ba41c), but I am not getting that. I want simple explanation how to use `InputPaneHelper` class (given in sample). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog post [Handling the virtual keyboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2012/07/09/tips-and-tricks-for-c-metro-developers-handling-the-virtual-keyboard.aspx) should answer your question. It includes a sample code demonstrating how to adjust the position of a flyout when the on-screen keyboard is shown/hidden. You can change it to adjust the layout of your page.

Comment: I don't have flyout, I just want to handle the appbar. Means, if user is typing in textbox with on-screen keyboard and he can use appbar. how to do that ? Abbbar doesn't has `VerticalOffset` property.

Comment: You can use Margins, RenderTransform, Canvas.Top, or any other layout mechanism to push the appbar where you want it.